# Are "sort" and "order" interchangeable?

Tags: difference, word-difference

Do both sentences mean the same thing?

- Please, would you order the papers by number?
- Please, would you sort the papers by number?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

"Sort" and "order" are generally interchangeable, and in your example, they are perfect synonyms. The one difference is that "order" can only be used for things that actually have a pre-defined ordering, like alphabetical or numeric. I could ask you to *sort* buttons by color, but asking you to *order* them by color wouldn't make much sense.

An *ordering* also implies an overall structure where each item has a specific relationship to the items before and after it. At the post office, for example, they'll *sort* letters by their destination, in which case they only care about each letter's category but not its relationship to other letters. The postman may then *order* letters for his delivery route, in which case each letter's relationship to the others is important.

Comment: That's a good point.  Sorting breaks things into categories.  Ordering is a type of sorting in which the categories have a defined a < b < c progression.

Comment: "Sort" and "order" might be interchangeable as verbs, but not as nouns; we don't put things in "alphabetical sort."

Comment: Ordering by color makes sense to some of us. Roy G. Biv, for example.

Answer (score 9):

"Order" in this instance means "to arrange methodically", while "sort" means "to group methodically". Which is correct depends on your desired outcome. If you have a set of numbered papers that you wish to be arranged in numerical order, then "order" is correct. If you have a set of numbered papers that you wish to have grouped into categories according to the numbers, then "sort" is correct.

Ex, if your set of papers have the numbers `{3, 5, 2, 1, 2, 5, 5, 4}`, then the result of "order" would be `{1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5}`, while the result of "sort" would be `{3}, {5, 5, 5}, {2, 2}, {1}, {4}`.

That being said, "sort" is often used in place of "order", with situational context making the intent clear.

Comment: I didn't know about this! Interesting point.

Comment: @ascallant:  do you have a source for the differentiation you claim?  To me, the two words, as verbs, are complete synonyms, with *sort* being used far more often, and with no necessary "group" connotation.  I can potentially **sort** some pool of items on multiple dimensions, some of which may result in more than one item in a bucket, and I can even **order** them by imposition.

Comment: @MMacD, reference your preferred dictionary, ex: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sort http://www.dictionary.com/browse/order

Comment: If I sort mail [an example of "sort" from Oxford] onto a table, the resulting "arrangement" is visibly "methodical", and none of the resulting "groups" need be of a size greater than 0.   To me, that seems sufficient evidence that we're looking at a pedantic distinction rather than a genuine difference in meaning.

Comment: The results of a sort can be in order, but it is not a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

In this context they would mean the same.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, but "order" is techie-sounding, possibly because that's the verb SQL uses for sort:  *SELECT foo FROM bar ORDER BY foo*

Comment: To the cutie pie who downticked me:  when was the last time you used the verb **order** in a non-technical context to mean "arrange" rather than "declare an intent to purchase"?

Comment: Maybe you rely too much on your personal colloquialisms for trying to make a neutral point about this. Please keep that in mind.